# How to assign a user to a new object with Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to assign the current logined user to an `account` model object in Django but for some reason the user is not assigned. I did try with `form.user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)` but problem is the same.

How could I do that ?

This is my code, a logged in user is able to create a new instance of the model but `instance.user` remains empty.

**models.py**

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
```

**forms.py**

```
class AccountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['name']
```

**view.py**

```
def create_account(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.user = request.user
            print('user', request.user) #  Return the user name correctly
            form.save()
            return redirect('accounts')
    else:
        form = AccountForm()
    return render(request,
                  'account/account_create.html',
                  {
                      'form': form
                  })
```

**account_create.html**

```
<h1>Create new account</h1>
<form action="{% url 'account_create' %}"
      method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
<button class="button" type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't need custom user model

Comment: oh, you mean settings.py with `AUTH_USER_MODEL` right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `form.user = request.user` , you should use:

```
form = AccountForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.user = request.user
```

Or use [`form.save(commit=False)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user
    instance.save()
```